Is there a way to overcome JSF namespace bottleneck with Maven on Rational Application Developer (RAD)?
I've rebuilt an existing web project as a Maven one.  Everything was OK.  However, when I open an xhtml page with JSF namespace tags (i.e. xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets") on Rational Application Developer, the developer goes "Annotated Project Initialization" and the entire editor gets bottlenecked for about 20 minutes until it goes back to normal.  An attempt to do something with the editor in that process results in "Program is not responding".  Anyone has an idea how to overcome this situation?
Screen 1
Screen 2
Rational Application Developer Version: 9.7.0
I've renewed project workspace, increased "Xms" and "Xmx" on "eclipse.ini", yet nothing has solved the problem.

I doubt that it's caused by Maven.. I would asked IBM for the problem..The other question is there reason to use RAD? Why not using Eclipse or IntelliJ?

Open "Progress" view and check what exactly is being processed at that moment. I guess XML/XHTML validation. I've seen this happen in large projects even though 20min is insane. You can turn off validation in project properties. @khmbarbaise: RAD is Eclipse based btw so any Eclipse-targeted answer might just work as good.

Thanks for the answers.
@BalusC: I've just checked "HTML Systax" and "XML Syntax" under "Validation" menu in project properties.  I'm afraid, they're both off.
I've added some screen caps of the "Progress" view during the incident. "Screen 1" is present for (relatively) a short time until it goes "Screen 2" in which the long duration bottleneck occurs.

By the way, this incident occurs only for the first loading of an .xhtml file after when the project workspace is opened or restarted and only if the file is opened with a complex editor like "HTML Editor", "XML Editor" or "Rich Page Editor".  I mean, if I close the file after the relief is reached and open any .xhtml file of the project or if the file is opened simply with "Text Editor" or "Generic Text Editor", everything is fine.
